# JavaPropsMapper in com.fasterxml.jackson version 2.15.2

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

After Upgrading jackson to version 2.15.2 I start getting this error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.IOContext.streamReadConstraints()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/StreamReadConstraints; at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.javaprop.JavaPropsParser.(JavaPropsParser.java:104) at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.javaprop.JavaPropsFactory.createParser(JavaPropsFactory.java:159) at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.javaprop.JavaPropsMapper.readPropertiesAs(JavaPropsMapper.java:107) at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.javaprop.JavaPropsMapper.readPropertiesAs(JavaPropsMapper.java:141) at`

I tried to line all jackson modules to same version but I still got the same issue

Comment: that method is in jackson-core 2.15.2 - can you double check that you upgraded all jackson jars to use 2.15.2?